# Cannot set the marker on a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-2

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAATB4WHBfI6bn_r2yHC5-cShQUwb554zi4F9w6VUOuAIqhCjZSuhSasJwxZuyueyW2ctbO3M8TQaJBIA' type='text/javascript'></script><script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[
      function load() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
            GEvent.addListener(map, 'moveend', function() {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = center.toString();
            });

                    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl()); // 
                    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl()); // 
                            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(55.752,37.616), 10);

                    var Moscow_point = new GLatLng(55.752,37.616);
                    var Moscow = new GMarker(Moscow_point, {title: 'Moscow'});
                    map.addOverlay(Moscow);
                }
      }
      //]]>
</script>  

</head>

<body  onload='load()' onunload='GUnload()'>
   <div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 300px'></div> 
</body>
```

Here is live example: http://travel.demas.me
Why can't I see the marker?

Comment: is there any reason your using v2? It's been deprecated for some time, v3 is much easier.

Comment: Where can I find info about v3?

Comment: I'm seeing this error through Chrome's Developer Tools:

`travel.demas.me:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

On this line:

   `document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = center.toString();`

Try removing this for debugging purposes.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Thanks.  Can you create the answer to give me ability to close the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing this error through Chrome's Developer Tools:

> travel.demas.me:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

On this line:

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = center.toString();
```

Try removing this for debugging purposes.